# Issue Importing .APK into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I created a .apk outside of eclipse using tiggr mobile (http://gotiggr.com)

i have the downloaded .apk and need to sign it - so i thought about running it through eclipse then signing it that way

im having the worse trouble importing it into eclipse.

does anyone have any other suggestions on signing this? i keep getting this message when uploading:

Market does not accept apks signed with the debug certificate. Create a new certificate that is valid for at least 50 years.
Market requires that the certificate used to sign the apk be valid until at least October 22, 2033. Create a new certificate.
Market requires the minSdkVersion to be set to a positive 32-bit integer in AndroidManifest.xml.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It would be faster to get the source code into eclipse via retyping it than to try and unsign and explode the apk, edit the manifest, fool the tools and sign the package.  The tools can be run at the command line anyways and eclipse would just make it harder.

One problem you have is that there are problems in your manifest. The market requires some attributes set in it that you did not need while doing developer builds.  You can open up the apk with anything that will open a zip file. You can edit text files with notepad. You package them up with ant by recreating the build.xml by hand. The instructions for signing things is here:

[Android Dev-Guide: Signing your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)

But what a LOT of work... and I am guessing you will need to do this multiple times just for one release to get the manifest right.  Then what do you do when you need to update your program?

Will the service not let you export the code in an easy to use way (because... wow... talk about evil)? Failing that cut and paste will save you time but you will almost certainly want to have it in eclipse or some IDE ready to make changes for your market release and build, package and to sign it.

Comment: it does allow export to HTML and a link to download the .apk 

i am new to this (obviously) but I do have a decent understanding. I do have a developer acccount set up and ready to go.

Comment: I am closing my eyes and imagining what export to html means. The mind's eye is recoiling. Copy and paste sounds like your best option.  I strongly recommend that you step into to your own development environment or this will get very painful very quickly. I just hope that this service wasn't doing some custom library thing. Not letting you at the code you write sounds sketchy to start with.

Comment: LOL okay i was afraid of this.... looks like copy and paste will be my new best friend lol

Answer (score 0):

That's not your issue. I suppose you compiled your app and now you're trying to publish it in the market. To do that, you need a private key whick in turn requires you to have a android market developer account.

Normally you can develop your app and install it into most devices but you can't submit apps to android market without a developer account.

If what you really want is only to import your app to eclipse, I suggest you to create a brand new android project and copy everything into it. It's easier and faster than adjusting everything!